# Converting a numeric dataframe with fractions to intergers in r via interpolation

Tags: r, interpolation

I have collected data which looks something like this:

```
wl       Spec.94 
299.784  57.95  
300.151  57.18
300.517  88.18
300.884  18.71
301.252  100.90
301.617  127.06
301.983  75.02
302.349  54.20
302.715  50.93
303.082  50.43
```

However, the program I use to analyze the data can only handle whole numbers for wl. I have an excel sheet I inherited that interpolates this data and produces this:

```
wl   Spec
300  41.03
301  61.77
302  51.84
```

I really don't know how that spreadsheet works, but the column titles that it auto-populates are Target Wl, Nearest Smaller Index, Nearest Smaller Wl, Upper Wl, Bias, Low-side value, High-side Value, and Interpolated value.

I need to be able to replicate this process in my r code, to make the analysis reproducible, but I have no idea where to start. How do I interpolate my data in r to get the values for Spec.95 at whole number values in wl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `seq`uence over the `round`ed `range` and feed `approx` with it.

```
wl <- do.call(seq, as.list(round(range(dat$wl))))
cbind(wl, Spec.94=approx(dat$wl, dat$Spec, wl)$y)
#      wl      Spec
# [1,] 300 57.49681
# [2,] 301 44.61772
# [3,] 302 74.05295
# [4,] 303 50.54172
```

However, the values are somewhat different, and I'm not sure how your specific excel code interpolates the `41.03` value which should be somewhere between `57.95` and `57.18`. Maybe you could figure that out?